# How to upload json file to Firebase Realtime database angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-realtime-database

I am using two functions below to convert excel sheet to json, Question How can I then upload this json file to Firebase Realtime database direct from my app ?

I want to add this function from my app

[image: Screenshot data]

```
onFileChange(ev) {
  let workBook = null;
  let jsonData = null;
  const reader = new FileReader();
  const file = ev.target.files[0];
  reader.onload = (event) => {
    const data = reader.result;
    workBook = XLSX.read(data, { type: 'binary' });

    jsonData = workBook.SheetNames.reduce((initial, name) => {
      const sheet = workBook.Sheets[name];
      initial[name] = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(sheet);
      return initial;
    }, {});
    const dataString = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = dataString.slice(0, 300).concat('...');
    this.setDownload(dataString);
  };
  reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
}


setDownload(data) {
  this.willDownload = true;
  setTimeout(() => {
    const el = document.querySelector('#download');
    el.setAttribute('href', `data:text/json;charset=utf-8,${encodeURIComponent(data)}`);
    el.setAttribute('download', 'xlsxtojson.json');
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: There's nothing specific to Angular for this. Once you have the JSON data in your code, you can write it to Firebase as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#write_data Is that not working for you? Or is the problem in loading the JSON data, and thus unrelated to Firebase.

Comment: thanks the link help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by Frank, there is nothing specific to Angular as you can upload your JSON to RTDB by following the documentation.

However, when working with Angular you'll want to use the [angular/fire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire) package which is the official library for Angular and Firebase development.

In your constructor, you'll import the AngularFireDatabase class

```ts
constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {}
```

And then here is your function that will upload the data:

```ts
  async uploadJSONToRTDB(yourDataHere: any): Promise<void> {
    // reference the node
    const ref = this.db.database.ref('ref/to/your/node');
    await ref.set(yourDataHere);
  }
```